# Duplicate values on elements in different media queries

Tags: html, css, duplicates, media-queries, element

I'm trying to clean up my huge media queries and I've removed every change in element values that are the same as the default element values so that this will show up instead.

My question is what choices I have when the duplicate values are stored in individual media queries?

Here is an example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.fa.fa-check
{
    font-size: 3em;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.fa.fa-shopping-cart
{
    font-size: 3em;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.fa.fa-user
{
    font-size: 3em;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
.fa.fa-check
{
    font-size: 3em;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.fa.fa-shopping-cart
{
    font-size: 3em;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.fa.fa-user
{
    font-size: 3em;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

I have lots of changes in element values that aren't duplicates inside of the media queries as well, so I can't combine them all together. Are there any other choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to assist with specifics without seeing your exact code base (or a real world example). With just the example above, I would recommend having a base class for each of those elements so you're not repeating those styles over and over again.

Edit: as an example of using a base class, for the above code you could make the following class and add it to each of the elements that you want to use those styling properties (so all the icon elements):

```
.standard-icon {
  font-size: 3em;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

This would eliminate a good chunk of duplicated code and create a more modular site design.

As far as media queries / duplicate values are concerned, here's how I handle responsive items on sites that I work with. There are three primary device sizes that I consider, `desktop`, `tablet`, and `mobile`. So if I'm creating an icon, for example with default styling across two or more device sizes, I'll do the following:

```
/* Default styling */
.icon-example {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0; /* Style which spans two or more queries */
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

@media @mobile-grid {
  margin: 30px 0; /* Overriding this style only on mobile */
}
```

Now I don't have to declare a `margin` value for every media query, just override it for the one that will be different. I'd also recommend looking into and using a CSS preprocessor like Sass or LESS. They're surprisingly simple to use and help keep your code as DRY as possible. Good luck!

Comment: I'll look into the CSS preprocessors! I've been struggling with a bunch of redefinition warnings because of repeating the styles and that's why I'm trying to clean up my media queries. Since this is not my strongest suit, do you care to explain how I would go about to make a base class for each of those elements? I've been trying to repeat as little as possible, but if I don't declare the element values for every media query it will automatically detect the default element values and both in the example above and in a lot of my other cases the default element values are different.

Comment: Sure thing, I added an example of a base class to my original answer! Media queries are a little tricky. Try to minimize them as much as possible and try not to overlap queries. Let me know if you have any more specific examples you need help with.

Comment: Okay, so would it look something like this ( .fa.fa-check { .standard-icon } ) or am I waaay of track right now?

Comment: My main problem is this: I need to change the values of the different elements in the media queries and the CSS validator picks this up as redefining the values and gives me warnings. Minimizing my media queries removes some of the warnings, but most of them are still there and I have no idea how to get rid of them. I have some examples if you have ever dealt with this kind of problem before and want to try. If not - I thank you kindly for your help :)

Comment: Ah, so you're mostly concerned about the validator warnings. Sometimes those are a little overly sensitive. You should be able to configure it to be more lenient or to avoid false warnings (which it sounds like some of these are). I'm on mobile right now but should be available in a couple hours to help further if needed. If you have your file up somewhere and the URL to the validator you're using, I'd be more than willing to take a closer look and see if there's anything you should actually be concerned about.

Comment: Yeah, both the validator warnings and the size of my media queries is concerning me. I'm using this validator set to all warnings: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator.html.en. Would the URL to my website be okay or do I need to upload the file somewhere? Thank you so much by the way!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. The website URL should be fine, I think, as long as the CSS file isn't minified.

Comment: My website URL is http://www.esigaretten.no/. It should all be there :)

Comment: Did you get a chance to check it out?

Comment: Sorry I kind of fell off the map. I ran some of the stylesheets through the validator provided and most of them said there were no errors. I didn't see any duplicate value errors. Were you already able to resolve the issue? Again, really sorry to come back to it so late! If you still need assistance, I'll need a little more info or to point me to the exact stylesheet you're having issues with. Thanks!